# Procedure is not ending

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am very new to PLSQL and stack overflow. I've written PLSQL code to post dummy entries in my assignment. I've wrote following code to post entries using dynamic SQL (I've read about it on this forum and internet and tried to use it). One of the issue I'm facing is that this procedure is not ending/exiting. I've looked into it multiple times but code seems find to me.

Could you please suggest what needs to be updated so I can post entries successfully?

Thanks in advance for kind help.

PS: This is my first question here. Please let me know if any updates are required.

```
--package spec
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE POST_ENTRIES AS
PROCEDURE POST_DAILY() ;

PROCEDURE IN_LEDGER_STAT_DAILY 
    (
        V_IDENTITY_CODE      NUMBER,    
        V_CONSOLIDATION_CD   NUMBER,    
        V_FINANCIAL_ELEM_ID  NUMBER,    
        V_ORG_UNIT_ID        NUMBER,   
        V_GL_ACCOUNT_ID      NUMBER,    
        V_COMMON_COA_ID      NUMBER,   
        V_PRODUCT_1_ID       NUMBER,   
        V_PRODUCT_ID         NUMBER,   
        V_PRODUCT_3_ID       NUMBER,    
        V_DATE               DATE,        
        V_AMOUNT             NUMBER,    
        V_MEMO_GL_ACCOUNT_ID NUMBER DEFAULT 0,  
        V_POSTINGTYPE        CHAR DEFAULT 'N', 
        V_BALANCE_TYPE_CD    NUMBER DEFAULT 0 
);

END POST_ENTRIES;
/


--package body
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY POST_ENTRIES AS


PROCEDURE POST_DAILY() AS

--BASE VARIABLES

i number := 0;
DS NUMBER := 82;
j number;
V_NEXT_WORKING_DATE DATE;

V_IDENTITY_CODE CONSTANT NUMBER(6):=112233;
V_CONSOLIDATION_CD   CONSTANT NUMBER(3):=100;
v_RECORDS_EXPECTED number;
v_RECORDS_ACTUAL number;


-- variables store result of dynamic cursor
V_SQL   VARCHAR2(2500);

TYPE  V_CURSOR IS REF CURSOR;

seq  V_CURSOR;

V_ORG_UNIT_ID           LEDGER_STAT_DLY.ORG_UNIT_ID%TYPE;
V_GL_ACCOUNT_ID         LEDGER_STAT_DLY.GL_ACCOUNT_ID%TYPE;
V_CMN_COA_ID            LEDGER_STAT_DLY. COMMON_COA_ID%TYPE;
V_PROD1                 LEDGER_STAT_DLY.PRODUCT_1_ID%TYPE;
V_PROD2                 LEDGER_STAT_DLY.PRODUCT_ID%TYPE;
V_PROD3                 LEDGER_STAT_DLY.PRODUCT_3_ID%TYPE;
V_DATE                  DAILYGL.AS_OF_DATE%TYPE;
V_POSTED                APPLICATION_TABLE_RECORD_COUNT.DLY_AS_OF_DATE%TYPE;
V_UPPER                 number;
V_DATE_PARAM            DATE;
V_END_BAL               NUMBER;
V_AVG_BAL               NUMBER;
V_SWITCH                NUMBER(1);
V_FLAG                  AL_LOOKUP.FLAG1%TYPE;
V_FIN                   AL_LOOKUP.FIN_ELEM%TYPE;
V_FIN1                  AL_LOOKUP.FIN_ELEM%TYPE;
V_ACCT_TYPE             NUMBER(2);


BEGIN


V_DATE:= '31-may-2019' -- this is getting returned from function but I've placed value here directly.

V_NEXT_WORKING_DATE := '03-Jun-2019'  -- this is getting returned from function but I've placed value here directly.

V_DATE_PARAM :=  V_DATE ; --POSTING DATE, START WITH V_DATE IT WILL INCREMENT INSIDE  WHILE LOOP. EXIT WHEN V_DATE_PARAM = V_NEXT_WORKING_DATE

------------------------------

WHILE V_DATE_PARAM < V_NEXT_WORKING_DATE

loop        

        V_SQL := 'SELECT A.ACCOUNT_TYPE, B.FIN_ELEM, A.ORG_UNIT_ID, A.GL_ACCOUNT_ID, B.CMN_COA_ID, B.PROD1, B.PROD2, B.PROD3,
                 SUM(CURRENT_BAL) AS CB_SUM, SUM(AVG_BAL) AS AB_SUM, B.FLAG1 FROM DAILYGL_TEST A, AL_LOOKUP B
                 WHERE A.GL_ACCOUNT_ID = B.GL_ACCT AND A.AS_OF_DATE = '||chr(39)||V_DATE||chr(39)|| 
                 ' and rownum <=3 GROUP BY A.ACCOUNT_TYPE, B.FIN_ELEM, A.ORG_UNIT_ID, A.GL_ACCOUNT_ID,B.CMN_COA_ID, B.PROD1, 
                   B.PROD2, B.PROD3, A.AS_OF_DATE, B.FLAG1';

    OPEN seq FOR V_SQL;

            LOOP
                V_SWITCH := 1;           
                FETCH seq INTO
                            V_ACCT_TYPE,   
                            V_FIN,
                            V_ORG_UNIT_ID,
                            V_GL_ACCOUNT_ID,
                            V_CMN_COA_ID,
                            V_PROD1, 
                            V_PROD2, 
                            V_PROD3,
                            V_END_BAL,  
                            V_AVG_BAL,  
                            V_FLAG;                                 

                IF V_FLAG = 'Y' THEN
                    V_SWITCH :=  -1;
                ELSE
                    V_SWITCH := 1;
                END IF;

                IF V_ACCT_TYPE = 5 OR V_ACCT_TYPE = 10 OR V_ACCT_TYPE = 20 OR V_ACCT_TYPE = 35 THEN
                    V_SWITCH := V_SWITCH * -1;
                END IF;


                IF (V_END_BAL <> 0 OR V_AVG_BAL <>0) THEN  
                         IF V_ACCT_TYPE = 1 OR V_ACCT_TYPE = 5 OR V_ACCT_TYPE = 10 OR V_ACCT_TYPE = 90 THEN    

                                V_FIN1 := SUBSTR(V_FIN,1,2) || '100';

                                IN_LEDGER_STAT_DAILY(V_IDENTITY_CODE,V_CONSOLIDATION_CD,V_FIN1,V_ORG_UNIT_ID,V_GL_ACCOUNT_ID,V_CMN_COA_ID,
                                                    V_PROD1, V_PROD2, V_PROD3,V_DATE_PARAM ,V_SWITCH * V_END_BAL);

                                IN_LEDGER_STAT_DAILY(V_IDENTITY_CODE,V_CONSOLIDATION_CD,V_FIN,V_ORG_UNIT_ID,V_GL_ACCOUNT_ID,V_CMN_COA_ID,
                                                    V_PROD1, V_PROD2, V_PROD3,V_DATE_PARAM,V_SWITCH * V_AVG_BAL);                      
                         ELSE
                                IN_LEDGER_STAT_DAILY(V_IDENTITY_CODE,V_CONSOLIDATION_CD,V_FIN,V_ORG_UNIT_ID,V_GL_ACCOUNT_ID,V_CMN_COA_ID,
                                                    V_PROD1, V_PROD2, V_PROD3,V_DATE_PARAM,V_SWITCH * V_END_BAL);               

                         END IF;
                END IF;

            END LOOP;

    CLOSE seq;

   V_DATE_PARAM := V_DATE_PARAM +1;

end loop;

END POST_DAILY; 

-------IN_LEDGER_STAT_DAILY procedure

PROCEDURE IN_LEDGER_STAT_DAILY 
    (
        V_IDENTITY_CODE      NUMBER,    
        V_CONSOLIDATION_CD   NUMBER,    
        V_FINANCIAL_ELEM_ID  NUMBER,    
        V_ORG_UNIT_ID        NUMBER,   
        V_GL_ACCOUNT_ID      NUMBER,    
        V_COMMON_COA_ID      NUMBER,   
        V_PRODUCT_1_ID       NUMBER,   
        V_PRODUCT_ID         NUMBER,   
        V_PRODUCT_3_ID       NUMBER,    
        V_DATE               DATE,        
        V_AMOUNT             NUMBER,    
        V_MEMO_GL_ACCOUNT_ID NUMBER DEFAULT 0,  
        V_POSTINGTYPE        CHAR DEFAULT 'N', 
        V_BALANCE_TYPE_CD    NUMBER DEFAULT 0 
)
IS

V_CNT NUMBER;
V_D      NUMBER;
V_DAY    CHAR(6);
V_MONTH CHAR(2);
V_MO NUMBER;
V_YEAR_S NUMBER;

-- variables store result of dynamic cursor
V_SL   VARCHAR2(2500);
V_TARGET_COLUMN VARCHAR2(6 CHAR);
k number := 0;


BEGIN              

   IF V_POSTINGTYPE = 'N' THEN

        IF NVL(V_AMOUNT,0) <> 0  THEN

                V_MO := (MONTH(V_DATE));
                V_MONTH := LPAD(V_MO,2,'0');
                V_YEAR_S := (YEAR(V_DATE));
                V_D := (DAY(V_DATE));
                V_DAY := 'DAY_' || lpad(V_D, 2, '0');

                SELECT /*+ index(a LEDGER_STAT_DLY_IDX02_IN) */ 
                COUNT(*) INTO V_CNT
                FROM LEDGER_STAT_DLY A
                WHERE
                IDENTITY_CODE         = NVL(V_IDENTITY_CODE,0)
                AND YEAR_S            = NVL(V_YEAR_S,0)
                AND MONTH_NO          = NVL(V_MONTH,0) 
                AND CONSOLIDATION_CD  = NVL(V_CONSOLIDATION_CD,0)
                AND FINANCIAL_ELEM_ID = NVL(V_FINANCIAL_ELEM_ID,0)
                AND ORG_UNIT_ID       = NVL(V_ORG_UNIT_ID,0)
                AND GL_ACCOUNT_ID     = NVL(V_GL_ACCOUNT_ID,0)
                AND COMMON_COA_ID     = NVL(V_COMMON_COA_ID,0)
                AND PRODUCT_1_ID      = NVL(V_PRODUCT_1_ID,0)
                AND PRODUCT_ID        = NVL(V_PRODUCT_ID,0)
                AND PRODUCT_3_ID      = NVL(V_PRODUCT_3_ID,0)
                AND COST_TYPE_ID      = NVL(V_MEMO_GL_ACCOUNT_ID,0)
                AND BALANCE_TYPE_CD   = NVL(V_BALANCE_TYPE_CD,0)    ;

                IF V_CNT = 0 THEN             
                    INSERT INTO LEDGER_STAT_DLY VALUES(
                    NVL(V_IDENTITY_CODE,0),
                    NVL(V_YEAR_S,0)       ,
                    NVL(V_MONTH,0)        ,
                    'D',
                    NVL(V_CONSOLIDATION_CD,0),
                    NVL(V_FINANCIAL_ELEM_ID,0),
                    NVL(V_ORG_UNIT_ID,0)     ,
                    NVL(V_GL_ACCOUNT_ID,0)   ,
                    NVL(V_COMMON_COA_ID,0)   ,
                    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                    NVL(V_PRODUCT_1_ID,0)    ,
                    NVL(V_PRODUCT_ID,0)    ,
                    NVL(V_PRODUCT_3_ID,0)    ,
                    TRUNC(NVL(V_ORG_UNIT_ID,0) / 10000000),
                    'USD',                             -- ISO_CURRENCY_CD
                    NULL,                              -- CURRENCY_TYPE_CD
                    NVL(V_BALANCE_TYPE_CD,0),
                    0,                                 -- VOLUME_ID
                    NVL(V_MEMO_GL_ACCOUNT_ID,0),       -- COST_TYPE_ID
                    0                                  -- CHANNEL_ID
                    );
              END IF;

             EXECUTE IMMEDIATE UTL_LMS.FORMAT_MESSAGE('UPDATE /*+ index(a LEDGER_STAT_DLY_IDX02_IN) */ LEDGER_STAT_DLY A
                           SET %s =  NVL(%s,0) + NVL(:THE_AMOUNT,0)
                           WHERE IDENTITY_CODE =  NVL(:THE_IDENTITY_CODE,0)
                              AND YEAR_S =  NVL(:THE_YEAR_S,0)
                              AND MONTH_NO = NVL(:THE_MONTH,0)
                              AND CONSOLIDATION_CD =  NVL(:THE_CONSOLIDATION_CD,0)
                              AND FINANCIAL_ELEM_ID = NVL(:THE_FINANCIAL_ELEM_ID,0)
                              AND ORG_UNIT_ID   = NVL(:THE_ORG_UNIT_ID,0)
                              AND GL_ACCOUNT_ID = NVL(:THE_GL_ACCOUNT_ID,0)
                              AND COMMON_COA_ID = NVL(:THE_COMMON_COA_ID,0)
                              AND PRODUCT_1_ID  = NVL(:THE_PRODUCT_1_ID,0)
                              AND PRODUCT_ID    = NVL(:THE_PRODUCT_ID,0)
                              AND PRODUCT_3_ID  = NVL(:THE_PRODUCT_3_ID,0)
                              AND COST_TYPE_ID    = NVL(:THE_MEMO_GL_ACCOUNT_ID,0)
                              AND BALANCE_TYPE_CD = NVL(:THE_BALANCE_TYPE_CD,0)', V_DAY, V_DAY)
            USING V_AMOUNT, V_IDENTITY_CODE, V_YEAR_S, V_MONTH, V_CONSOLIDATION_CD, V_FINANCIAL_ELEM_ID, V_ORG_UNIT_ID, 
            V_GL_ACCOUNT_ID, V_COMMON_COA_ID, V_PRODUCT_1_ID, V_PRODUCT_ID, V_PRODUCT_3_ID, V_MEMO_GL_ACCOUNT_ID, V_BALANCE_TYPE_CD;

        END IF; 

    END IF;



END IN_LEDGER_STAT_DAILY;


END POST_ENTRIES ;
/
```

Comment: Have you inserted or updated any data in LEDGER_STAT_DLY in another session, and left it uncommitted? The update in your procedure might just be blocked. (Incidentally, the first query doesn't need to be dynamic; and you should be using actual dates rather than strings that then rely on implicit conversion and NLS settings.)

Comment: there's package body but no specification part shared here.

Comment: @AlexPoole: I inserted data in ```Dailygl_test table``` but committed it. I've closed the session which wasn't ending. ```Could you please suggest should I just run COMMIT again to ensure issue#1, as pointed by you, is resolved. If not, what else should I do to address issue#1? Before running the proc, I've set the values of column to zero and proc has updated value for Day_31 column for May month but it never went to day_01 and day_02 column of June month``` ...

Comment: ...I've tried to use Dynamic query and this is my first attempt. Could you please tell me by editing my code or commenting how I can pass actual date as per your suggestion? Moreover, Date shouldn't be an issue, as per my understanding, because I ran select query separately and it gave the desired result.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan: Done. Just edited the code part of question.

Comment: well, but still has missing parts.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan: Sorry but I haven't understood. Could you please explain what is missing? Also, If spec won't match with body then it won't compile and run. I don't think it's an issue here.

Comment: I added the first line, and it's OK now, it can be compiled.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan: Thanks. Apart from this, could you please suggest if it's ok and will end? Last time I ran, it got stuck. I posted it here to get it reviewed. To me it looks good but wanted to see experts opinions so asked here.

Comment: `'31-may-2019'` is not a DATE, it is a **string**. Use `DATE` literal or `TO_DATE()` function, e.g. `TO_DATE('31-may-2019', 'dd-mon-yyyy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=american')`

Comment: You should use bind variables for opening the cursor (as you do for the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`), i.e. `V_SQL := 'SELECT ...  AND A.AS_OF_DATE = :V_DATE ...'; OPEN seq FOR V_SQL USING V_DATE;`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: Thanks a lot!! I've updated date part. For bind variable, I am printing query hence passing it like this so value of ```v_date``` gets printed. If i use bind variable then ```DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_SQL)``` is printing ```:v_Date``` instead of v_date value. hence I'm using it in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop in your first procedure never exits; you need to add something like

```
                EXIT WHEN seq%NOTFOUND;
```

i.e:

```
...
    OPEN seq FOR V_SQL;

            LOOP
                V_SWITCH := 1;           
                FETCH seq INTO
                            V_ACCT_TYPE,   
                            V_FIN,
                            V_ORG_UNIT_ID,
                            V_GL_ACCOUNT_ID,
                            V_CMN_COA_ID,
                            V_PROD1, 
                            V_PROD2, 
                            V_PROD3,
                            V_END_BAL,  
                            V_AVG_BAL,  
                            V_FLAG;                                 

                EXIT WHEN seq%NOTFOUND;

                IF V_FLAG = 'Y' THEN
...
```

As mentioned in comments, the cursor query in that procedure doesn't need to be dynamic; and you should be using actual dates rather than strings that then rely on implicit conversion and NLS settings - or at a minimum, explicit conversion between strings and dates.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, ```V_DATE:= USB.DLY_AOD(82);```. I'm calculating returned date from utilizing existing function and assigning it to V_DATE and then passing it as string and query runs fine. I used it so that i can see the value of date in console when dynamic query runs. Would you suggest sth  as below with to_date()...

Comment: ```q'[SELECT A.ACCOUNT_TYPE, B.FIN_ELEM, A.ORG_UNIT_ID, A.GL_ACCOUNT_ID, B.CMN_COA_ID, B.PROD1, B.PROD2, B.PROD3,
                 SUM(CURRENT_BAL) AS CB_SUM, SUM(AVG_BAL) AS AB_SUM, B.FLAG1 FROM DAILYGL_TEST A, AL_LOOKUP B
                 WHERE A.GL_ACCOUNT_ID = B.GL_ACCT AND A.AS_OF_DATE = to_date(V_DATE, 'dd-mon-yyyy') 
                 GROUP BY A.ACCOUNT_TYPE, B.FIN_ELEM, A.ORG_UNIT_ID, A.GL_ACCOUNT_ID,B.CMN_COA_ID, B.PROD1, 
                   B.PROD2, B.PROD3, A.AS_OF_DATE, B.FLAG1]'```

Comment: As long as the function always returns a string in that format (why doesn't it just return a date?) and the same language for the month abbreviations *8-)